# Clustering a fully connected graph

Tags: clustering, data-visualization

I've a graph representing a social network ( 597 nodes, 177906 edges). Each edge has a weight saying how much two nodes are similar. I'd like to apply some clustering algorithm to this network but I think I need to cut some edge. Is there a commonly used threshold to do this?
Can you suggest any particular algorithm? I was suggested to use K-means but I think it badly fit to my data space.

Comment: http://www.pnas.org/content/103/23/8577.full is a very standard approach

Answer (score 1):

600 nodes is tiny, so you shouldn't have scalability problems.

Try:

1. Hierarchical agglomerative clustering (implement it for similarity, not distance!)
2. Spectral clustering
3. Affinity propagation
4. K-medoids with affinity

Answer (score 0):

So you basically have a *similarity matrix*, more than a graph. Performing classic clustering (by opposition to graph partitioning), through an algorithm such as $k$-medoids makes sense, in this situation (except clustering algorithms generally use distance or dissimilarity instead of similarity).

If you want to use a graph partitioning approach, and need to build a sparser graph, have a look at this article describing several methods for this purpose: ([von Luxburg 2007](http://www.kyb.mpg.de/fileadmin/user_upload/files/publications/attachments/Luxburg07_tutorial_4488%5B0%5D.pdf)), section 2.2.

Did you produce the similarity matrix yourself based on some description of your nodes?

Comment: I have a .txt file where each line is in the form:
`source:dest:weight`. The graph in non directed.  The bigger the weight is the more similar the nodes are.
I said I had a graph cause I'm working with networkx.
I built the data set by myself parsing infos from the web

Comment: Ok, then you can have a look at the paper I mentioned, it proposes methods to build graphs containing only a part of the possible edges.

Comment: K-means does expect a n x p coordinate matrix, not a distance matrix!

Comment: @Anony-Mousse you're right, sorry. I was thinking about $k$-medoids. And since viral has the node positions, (s)he can apply whichever.

Comment: Why do you assume he has positions?it's a social network, similarity is likely not position based.

Comment: I did not mean necessarily a position in some physical space, but rather some set of attributes describing the nodes, in general. I assume viral has such data because (s)he apparently processed the similarity matrix himself. But indeed, it's also possible that the similarity matrix was obtained based on non-numerical data, such as text or categorical variables. Could you tell us, viral?

Comment: Right, I obtained the matrix processing non-numerical data. So I only got distances (similarity) between nodes not their position in the space

Comment: Ok. Note that you can still apply the methods described in von Luxburg's paper to get a sparser graph (see section 2.2).

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I corrected my answer based on your remarks.

Comment: I think I'll use python library sklearn to do my clustering things. Do u know how can I let my data fit to this library?

Comment: No, sorry. I generally use R for these tasks.