# Community Detection for Complete Weighted Network

Tags: clustering, graph-theory, weighted-data, model-based-clustering

I am wondering if someone who has experience in trying to perform community detection algorithm with complete graph with weighted network.
As weighted networks represents the similarity of each node and hence it is complete network considered all pairwise of nodes.
The adjacent matrix can be represented in the following table:

```
NODE   A     B     C
  A    -    0.2   0.3
  B   0.2    -    0.7
  C   0.3   0.7    -
```

So can I just perform any weighted related community detection methods on this?

Is there any other method? Or am I mistaking something?

Comment: Have you seen this post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/266493/clustering-a-fully-connected-graph ?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks!